# parallel presentation player

Tags: flash, html, html5-video, presentation

I am looking for a Web-based Player which can display i.e. the presentation on the left side and the lecturer on the right side. With a button click (or other action) the user has control about the visibility of the lecturer, but the presentation is always visible.

This is one example: http://www.longtailvideo.com/addons/plugins/137/SlideSync-%28Beta%29?q=video%20effects but its not ready yet and does not fit my needs so well..

I just thought of just 2 jwPlayers side by side with a bit of javascript to synchronize them.. does anyone has expirience with this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your question is a bit vague. Is there something specific you need to know about? Perhaps read up on ExternalInterface (actionscript) for a starting point.

Comment: Actually I'm looking for a ready-to-go solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

guess there is no ready to go solution yet, but you could set up an html5-player and listen to the timeupdate event via javascript.

f.e.

```
<video id="videoplayer" src="yourfile.mp4" .../>
<script>
  var player = document.getElementById("videoplayer");
  player.addEventListener('timeupdate', function(){

      var currentTime =player.currentTime;

      //define several intervalls for slices
      if( currentTime > 0 && currentTime < 10 ){

          //show slice-Image in html Canvas
      }
      else if... //different interval!

  });

</script>
```

this is only pseudocode to geive you an idea how to implement!! there are many ways how you can make this more dynamic (intervalls via json, xml....)
hope it helps!