# Need a good framework for video presentations on the web

Tags: html, video, html5-video, presentation

I'm looking for a framework that allows for dynamically showing slides at certain points in a video presentation. It would need to be cross browser compatible including IE 7 and 8 as well as tablets like the iPad. It does not need to be completely done for me just a good starting point with a lot of the cross browser stuff done and preferably fairly easy to customize. I have an understanding of how all this works just would like some help with the annoying stuff.

If anyone has any suggestions that would be great. I have been doing some searching but it's always nice to see what others are saying about some of these solutions. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

i just answered to a similar post last week ago. ( [parallel presentation player](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9099554/parallel-presentation-player/9194822#9194822) ). still i haven t got THE cross browser compatible solution...

you can check this out, never tried, but it should do the thing you are looking for: http://www.longtailvideo.com/addons/plugins/137/SlideSync-(Beta)    it is flash based, so ie 7 and 8 will work, but no ipad

with html5 you could easily set up some script which listens to the actual time in the video, but as you might now, not compatible for ie7 and ie8...

i just add the "Pseudocode" i wrote in the other post for a simple html5 solution

```
<video id="videoplayer" src="yourfile.mp4" .../>
<script>
  var player = document.getElementById("videoplayer");
  player.addEventListener('timeupdate', function(){

  var currentTime =player.currentTime;

  //define several intervalls for slices
  if( currentTime > 0 && currentTime < 10 ){

      //show slice-Image in html Canvas
  }
  else if... //different interval!

});

</script>
```

edit: this is just an idea...you can define the intervalls in a better way using json or xml....

Comment: Do you know of any Flash video players that can give time code information to JavaScript similar to the way HTML5 does it? If this is possible then I could have a video stack that falls back to the Flash video but can still grab time code information from it.

Comment: it is possible. you can use external interfaces in your flash player to call functions in javascript. 
but i don't know any player which does this automatically. it s not a big deal if you re well known to flash, still i guess you have to implement it yourself..

edit: you can also check osmf flash player (there s an easy way to set up)
check walkthrough 1 here http://osmf.org/developers.html

and use the time event which triggers external interface: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/org/osmf/events/package-detail.html

hope it helps

Comment: Great I will check this out later and will let you know if this will help.

Comment: I also came across this which looks promising... in case you are interested http://flowplayer.org/demos/events/index.html

Comment: I know this is long over due and is probably useless information now but I figured I would comment anyways. I ended up going with FlowPlayer for the IE fallback and writing my own small framework for setting cuepoints depending on what the user's browser was capable of playing. I hope to at some point clean it up a little and maybe put it up on github for those smarter than me to take and make better if anyone is interested.

Answer (score 0):

What about silverlight? there is MediaElement that can be useful.
Silverlight working on IE 6 and above and on all main browsers.

http://www.microsoft.com/getsilverlight/locale/en-us/html/installation-win-SL4.html

I'm not sure about IPad.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb980132(v=vs.95).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [PresentationTube](http://presentationtube.com/), a new way for producing and sharing video presentations with slide and scrollable thumbnails